# php convert time stamp to seconds (2 hours 12 min or 2:12:00)

Tags: php, seconds

Hi I'm trying to convert a timestamp to seconds. Currently the time stamp will be transmitted in two forms and want to prepare for either. However I think im making it harder on myself with the methods i've tried.

So for example the input is

**1 hour 1 minute 1 second** or **2 hours 2 minutes 2 seconds** <-- for plural

I want the final output to be the example below so i can then convert that number to just seconds:

**01:01:01** or **02:02:02**

I don't know what the case will be and it will be a parameter passed through url and here is what i've tried so far but like i said, its not displaying right:

```
$recent_time = htmlspecialchars($_GET["time"]);

$recent_time = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", ":", $recent_time);
    $recent_time = preg_replace("/(.)\\1+/", "$1", $recent_time);

echo $recent_time;
```

So as you can see I replace all letters with a colon and make sure the colons don't repeat so the output will be xx:xx:xx however sometimes the output isn't accurate here is how i would translate the output to seconds:

```
$str_time = preg_replace("/^([\d]{1,2})\:([\d]{2})$/", "00:$1:$2", $recent_time);
        sscanf($str_time, "%d:%d:%d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
        $time_seconds = $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds;
        $sum_total = $time_seconds + $old_time;
```

The issue is that if it's only min + sec it doesn't translate it into seconds properly. so for example the time is 10 minutes 13 seconds it will output `10:13:` but it doesn't convert it to seconds properly cause its not 00:10:13. I've tried to truncate the final colon but it still can't differentiate between mintues/sec/hours

```
$recent_time = substr_replace($recent_time ,"",-1);
```

*EDIT*

```
$converted_time = date('H:i:s',strtotime('$recent_time', strtotime('midnight')));
```

Comment: Can we assume that input can only be in format such as `%d hour[s] $d minute[s] %d second[s]`?

Comment: @lolbas correct, the url parameter will only consist of that format for example : `www.somewebsite.com/info.php/?time=x hour[s] x minute[s] x second[s]` but it wont be 0 hour 0 minutes 25 seconds if it's only been 25 seconds it will just say `www.somewebsite.com/info.php/?time=25 seconds`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use php strtotime function instead

```
date('H:i:s',strtotime('1 hour 1 minute 1 second', strtotime('midnight'))); // 01:01:01
date('H:i:s',strtotime('2 hours 2 minutes 2 seconds', strtotime('midnight'))); // 02:02:02
date('H:i:s',strtotime('10 minutes 13 seconds', strtotime('midnight'))); // 00:10:13
```

Comment: I went to the php website and looked up php `strtotime` and it looks absolutely cleaner than what i've been doing. but i am learning, i did try to learn it myself, but i got stuck.... the output is only showing 17:00:00 im assuming its the 'midnight' part. what i gather from [this website](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) 'H:i:s' is the format I want it to be in, which is correct, the string I want it format is '1 hour 1 min 1 sec` or in my case `$recent_time`, The website says its the time the calculation should be given until. But it only outputs 17:00:00. see edit

Comment: strtotime make time of 1st argument relative to the 2nd. Saying midnight we set base 00:00:00. (Without it, it will be current time). In result, "time part" is time produced from the string (and today date, but this does not matter in the case)

Comment: thanks for explaining, so is my edited string : `$converted_time = date('H:i:s',strtotime('$recent_time', strtotime('midnight')));` not valid? i did read on the site if you don't include a time() it will default to `now` which makes sense why we set it to midnight. I just don't get why the output is only `17:00:00` regardless of input

Comment: remove quotes from here - `strtotime('$recent_time',`

Comment: duh!!!!! oh man. embarrassing. I was looking for something above my skills lol thank you for your patience and understanding. i really mean it. I really appreciate the people on here that treat people trying to learn with respect. thanks

Comment: Good luck in your studies! :) !